# Ios - how to build alinear chart using core graphics ro Quartz 2D?

Tags: ios, iphone

i want to build a linear chart show the user progress of loosing or gain weight , any help how to start , 
how can i draw the x and y access with data acoording to diet date and desired weight , 
and then draw the progress according to them

[image: this an example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be done most easily using [core-plot](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/), a framework designed for creating 2D charts and graphs.

Another perhaps easier solution would be to use [PNChart for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pnchart).

Comment: im trying to use it but it seems complicated , i follow this link to build a linear chart but many exceptions accored :( http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2

Comment: If you choose to stick with core-plot, you should accept this answer and then post additional questions for the specific problems you are encountering. can't promise it will be simple, but working through that guide is a good place to start

Comment: i will try to use  Quartz 2D as in this link http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-graph-with-quartz-2d/  is it a good choice ?? i have no time to try every thing im in trouble

Comment: seems like a fine way to do it